# Phonegap 3.2.0 android application Back button cutomization for some pages only

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using phonegap 3.2.0
I want to customize back button in android application for some pages only. For other page it behave as like its default behavior.

I've Seen many post to change behavior of back button but didn't find anywhere that how to toggle between default and customize behavior on change page.

There are 4 pages in my application

- login
- create-post

  - finish-post
- settings

Sidebar Navigation menu has three links

- Create post (for create-post page)
- Settings (For settings page )
- Logout (For logout app)

finish-post only open after fill the form on create-post pages. After finish a post user will redirect again to create-post page.

Question : When user press back button on create-post page when he came from login or finish-post page then app should exit otherwise it should take me on last visited page.

I tried following code

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady()
{
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(e, data){
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){ 
            var lastpageid = data.prevPage.attr('id'); //LAST PAGE ID
            var currentpageid = $.mobile.activePage[0].id //CURRENT PAGE ID

        if(currentpageid == 'create-post' && (lastpageid == 'login' || lastpageid == 'finish-post')){
                navigator.app.exitApp(); 
            }else{
                return true; // WHAT TO PUT HERE ?
                //WHEN I PUT $.mobile.changePage('#'+lastpageid, { transition: 'slide' }, true); 
                //THEN FIRST IT OPENING LOGIN PAGE THEN AGAIN create-post PAGE
                //AGAIN AND AGAIN DOING LIKE THIS. 
                //THIS BEHAVIOR OCCUR WHEN I PRESS BACK BUTTON ON finish-post.
            } 
        }, false);
    });
 }
```

Comment: by using `pagebeforeshow you add multiplied bindings on the same button. be specific and use `pageinit` with page's id i.e. `$(document).on("pageinit", "#create-post, #login", function () { your code });`.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried "**history.back();**"

I think it will solve your issue.